# Parent / Child Click Tab

Tags: jquery

I have a tab...

```
<span id="Tab_1" class='Global_OFF'>
    <span id="Tab_Name_1">Tab Name</span>
    <span id="Delete_1" class="Tab_Delete">X</span>
</span>
```

I have two jquery actions that happen. One is when I click the tab itself which is class 'Global_Off' and the other is when I click the delete button which is class 'Tab_Delete'. Unfortunately, when I click class 'Tab_Delete', it will fire class 'Global_OFF'. Is there a way to click 'Tab_Delete' without firing 'Global_OFF' in this  format?

Comment: It made it easier from the design end. Is it bad?

Comment: It's not bad, I just wonder if there might be a more _semantically correct_ way of marking it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on delete button click event which will prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent `span.Global_OFF`.

```
$('.Tab_Delete').click(function(e){
     //Other stuff

     e.stopPropagation();
});
```